# How to set RetryPolicy using container SAS with Azure Java SDK?

Tags: java, android, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, sas-token

I am implementing an Android app where I need to upload images to a blob container using a container SAS.

Currently using the full endpoint credentials as a connection string, I can add a retry policy to my `CloudBlobClient` using the following code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount
        .parse(storageConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions();
RetryPolicy policy = new RetryExponentialRetry(BACKOFF_DELTA, MAX_RETRIES);
options.setRetryPolicyFactory(policy);
blobClient.setDefaultRequestOptions(options);

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(containername);
```

Now, as I am switching from the account key to SAS, I don't know how to create a `CloudBlobClient` using the SAS signature I have for my container. I can create both `CloudBlobClient` and `CloudBlobContainer` using the URL with SAS, but the client is created with anonymous credentials and cannot be associated with my container:

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(URI.create(containerurl));
CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(URI.create(containerurl));
```

Is there a way to add `RetryPolicy` directly to the `CloudBlobContainer` or create an authenticated `CloudBlobClient` associated with my container class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was tagged with both 'Java' and 'Android', so I'll reply about the Java SDK, Android should be similar.

There are a few options here:

- All API's that make service calls offer [an overload](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlob.java#L1218) that takes in a BlobRequestOptions object.  Settings in this object (including the retry policy) override defaults from the client.
- When constructed with a URI, CloudBlobContainer and CloudBlob objects internally create a default BlobServiceClient object, which you can access with the [getServiceClient()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlobContainer.java#L1199) method.  You can then set defaults on this.
- If you want to continue to use a connection string, you can create one with a SAS token, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string).
- You can create a [StorageCredentials](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature.java) object using a SAS token, which you can then use to create a CloudStorageAccount object.  Note that if you opt for this route, you will need to use one of the CloudStorageAccount constructors that either take [an account name](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/CloudStorageAccount.java#L869) or [an endpoint](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/CloudStorageAccount.java#L919), otherwise the SDK will have no way of constructing the URL for your Storage Account.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, that did it! The overload for upload that takes the option was the best solution for me and it worked!